# Launching activity from the background, doesn't run the function in onResume()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

In my application, when the app stops recording audio it launches another activity and runs the function automaticSync() in the onResume(), but when the device is locked it does not run the function from the background, is there a way to run a function in the second activity from the background when launched.

Recording Activity launching another activity

```java
if (autoSyncSwitchSelected1) { // If user's preference is automatic syncing then set the 
                               // activity to syncRecording which will call the 
                               // automaticSync() method
                                    
   handleSelectedFiles("syncRecordings", 3); // Start activity RecordingsExplorer for result
                            
}
```

Recording Explorer

```java
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("onResume");
    // get default shared preferences file:
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
    autoSyncSwitchSelected = settings.getBoolean(Config.PREF_AUTO_SYNC, true);
    if(autoSyncSwitchSelected) {
        automaticSync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OnResume](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onresume) is the state in which the app interacts with the user. It's called when the app is in the foreground. As you said *"when the device is locked it does not run the function from the background"*, yes this is correct. [OnResume](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onresume) will only be called when the app is in the foreground. When your activity is no longer visible to the user or in the background, it has entered the [OnStop](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onstop) State. Have a look on [Activity-lifeCycle-Concept](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc).

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but is there a way to run a function in the second activity when the device is locked, because my application launches the second activity when the device is locked, now it won't run any of the function I saw in Activity-lifeCycle-concept

Comment: You shouldn't start an activity if the app is in the background. Instead, you can use a background service. You can read this [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

Answer (score 0):

the OnResume() only works when the phone is not in locked state.
You can try other methods like Background Service, Broadcast Receiver or you can override using onStop method